# Discords.js send a message to every channel in a server

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that sends a message to every channel in a server. The function responsible for this action is the following.

```js
if (message.content === "!broadcast") {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES", "ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send("You don't have the required permissions to use that silly");
    message.guild.channels.cache.forEach(channel => channel.send('test'))
    return
  }
```

When invoked, it gives a TypeError and the bot crashes. If you can, please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

`TypeError: channel.send is not a function`

Comment: what does message.guild.channels.cache data look like? I am not sure what exactly you are trying to loop over. Can you update to include what you get when you console.log(JSON.stringify(message.guild.channels));

Comment: Also, on the first if condition, does that message "You don't have..." successfully send when a user does not have permission? Please update to also include what debugging you have tried :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.channels.cache` property on the `message.guild` is a collection of [`GuildChannels`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel). This collection has all channels, including VoiceChannels, CategoryChannels, etc. Most of these GuildChannel types don't have a function called `send()`, only a [`TextChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) and a [`NewsChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/NewsChannel?scrollTo=send) have this function.

To fix the issue, you'd first need to filter on the types of channels that have this `send()` function before sending the message. Take a look at the example code below and give it a try. It works by checking if the [`GuildChannel.type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=type) is either `text` or `news`.

```js
if (message.content === "!broadcast") {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES", "ADMINISTRATOR")) {
        return message.channel.send("You don't have the required permissions to use that silly");
    }

    message.guild.channels.cache
        .filter(channel => ['text', 'news'].includes(channel.type))
        .forEach(channel => channel.send('test'));
}
```